# Add glare to square on CorelDRAW X8

Tags: corel-draw

I am new to CorelDRAW and I am wondering how I can add a glare to a square. I currently have a 300x300 pixel square with a border radius of 20px and I am trying to add a glare to it like the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That effect is created by adding another block on top of your 100% color block with a gradient in it.  Of course, reshaping the bottom portion so you end up with two shapes.  the top layer has the gradient shape with the top corners rounded like the square and the bottom domed.  The bottom layer is your round corner square.  I can give you a step by step with pictures of that is unclear.  I am not super familiar with Corel Draw, but from what I remember is fairly similar to Illustrator for the basic tools.